# <col> width and padding - IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

IE 7 adds the padding to the total width of the column. Firefox and Chrome include the padding in the width. How do I get consistency across browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Col Padding</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      #col1
      {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #theTab td
      {
        background-color: green;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #theBar
      {
        width: 200px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='theBar'></div>
    <table id='theTab'>
      <col id='col1'/>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about collapse the table borders, and set the table padding to 0px and border to 0px

Comment: @Anagio That will work except for when you actually want padding and borders. So the question is how do I get the same size table in all browsers and still control the width of each column and have borders and padding in each <td>?

Comment: What about doing something like this http://jsfiddle.net/peter/Wr5bs/1/ i'm not familiar with each browsers standards and don't have IE installed to check but this rendered the same result. Does it help any?

Answer (score 2):

IE8 and later, and everything else you're likely to have to support, support overriding how box sizing works per-element using the [`box-sizing` CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing).

If you have to support IE7, set the box sizing on whatever you need to `border-box`; IE7 will ignore the property but follow that model anyway, and everything else will match IE7's behaviour.

That said, IE6 and later *should* support the W3C standard model when in "standards mode". You should doublecheck your DOCTYPE and such to make sure they'll invoke that rendering mode and not "quirks mode".

Answer (score 0):

Either make a separate stylesheet for IE and load it with a conditional statement, or accept the IE is the lesser browser and doesn't display well-written code correctly.

option 1 seems the most satisfying though ;-)

Comment: While usually I'd agree with the jab at IE, this is an instance where the W3C standard was (seemingly arbitrarily) chosen to do something else than what IE and Netscape did at the time. To add insult to injury, I've yet to find someone make a convincing argument why content-sizing is a better model than border-sizing. So in my opinion, this would be a case where the W3C is wrong, if W3C wasn't always right by fiat.