# IE7 - fixing column width issue when cell has padding

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-7, html4

I'm having some problems with IE7 and table with fixed-layout and fixed column sizes. Most browsers use the column width to set the size of the cell including padding yet IE7 seems to set it excluding padding so there is an over-hang.

I've searched, searched and searched again for a solution but I can't find anything decent except applying "box-sizing: border-box" to everything else and thats out of the question. Dropping "table-layout: fixed" also works but too much other code relys on this.

How can I get consistency across browsers?

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" -->
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      table {
        width: 200px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      .first {
        width: 50px;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .second {
        width: 150px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .alt {
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col class="first" />
        <col class="second" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td class="alt">bar</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Similar question: [<col> width and padding - IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641872/col-width-and-padding-ie7)

IE7 SS 
[image: IE7 screenshot]

IE9 SS
[image: IE9 SS]

Comment: You need to use the conditional statements.

<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE7 here
<![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn`t support table padding. You need to apply the pad to the table data cell instead.